# .dircolors does not affect existing files, only new files

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I recently decided that the terminal color scheme that Ubuntu uses is not optimal.  I have edited .dircolors and it worked...for the most part.  The issue I am having is I added two custom file extensions to .dircolors which are .R and .cpp.  I wanted to make these different colors, but it only applies if I create a new file, say test.R or test.cpp, not for my already existing .R and .cpp files.

Any ideas why existing ones are not taking on the new color settings in .dircolors?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the `~/.dircolors` is not read by `ls` directly, but used at shell startup to set an environment variable `LS_COLORS` that `ls` uses. I wager that you used two different terminals when listing the directories, one which was started after modifying `~/.dircolors`. To make the change take effect in the existing terminal use `eval $(dircolors ~/.dircolors)`.

Colors are also assigned based on the mode of the file. It could be that your older files are, for example, executable and are therefore get that color in preference to the one you defined. On my system, these mode-based colors are for setuid and setgid files, files with capabilities, and executable files.

Comment: I tried running that command.  Nothing changes.  I have the commands to run .dircolors in my .bashrc file so its ran everytime a terminal window opens.  And the weird part is that it changes for new files that I add, but not the existing ones.  Unless I write over them.